# Run polymer js application on localhost using any Java server (not python or any other related )

Tags: java, polymer

I have watched some videos regarding set up of polymer js application. In some, they say start `SimpleHTTPServer` and deploy your app, but this server is a module of python, I don't want to install it.

So I want to run this application using some Java related server.

Comment: the best thing to do would be: suck it up and install python, or get a different tutorial.

Comment: @ApoorvaDixit  Why Java?

Comment: Because my backend code is in java, I dont want to install another language just for a server. I just want to know is it possible to run polymer app using some Java related server, if its not possible then I will have to ask my client for python. Thank you

Comment: The local server is just for development. Is your client also developing the app? If not, they shouldn't care what type of server you use. They'll just take your bundle, and use any server they choose (which could be Python, Java, Node, or whatever).

Comment: So u mean it is not possible without SimpleHTTPServer or installing python?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Apache Tomcat (although any Java web server would work). Create a simple static web application (Eclipse creates a template for a new web project) and add your polymer files to it. Deploy to Tomcat and point your browser to http://localhost:8080 (or whichever ip:port you have configured)

While in active development use Eclipse to deploy and sync web application to Tomcat. Refer to Eclipse documentation for that.

For production deployment, first use polymer-cli to create a bundled package and then deploy the contents of the bundled (or unbundled) package as a web application.